# How to convert a lookup to an expression to use in `QuerySet.annotate`?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

The subject may be a little bit obscure, so here is an example.  Let's say I have a model:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
```

I want a QuerySet containing a `has_user` field that would basically map to the following SQL query

```
select *, user_id is not null as has_user
from app_testmodel
```

How can I explain this `has_user` field to Django when using `QuerySet.annotate`?

---

I am aware that Django has concepts like `models.F`, `models.Q`, `models.lookups`, `models.expressions` etc., but I am unable to understand how to apply them in my case.  To the best of my knowledge, this is a matter of converting a "lookup" to a boolean "expression" where

- A "lookup" is something like `'user_id__isnull'` or `lookups.IsNull(models.F('user_id'))` in Django ORM language.
- An "expression" is something like `expressions.ExpressionWrapper(?, output_field=models.BooleanField())`.

So far I only managed to convert the `user_id is not null` expression to `case when user_id is not null then true else false end`, which maps to Python code like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import expressions

# ...
qs = TestModel.objects.all().annotate(has_user=
    expressions.Case(
        expressions.When(
            user__isnull=False,
            then=expressions.Value(True),
        ),
        default=expressions.Value(False),
        #
        # Tell Django the expected type of the field, see `output_field` in
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/
        #
        output_field=models.BooleanField()))
```

But it is an awkward workaround. There must be a better solution: more proper, easier, and cleaner w.r.t. to Python code and the resulting SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use `models.Q` and `expressions.ExpressionWrapper`:

```
qs = TestModel.objects.all().annotate(
    has_user=expressions.ExpressionWrapper(
        models.Q(user_id__isnull=False),
        output_field=models.BooleanField()
    )
)
```